# How to remove a Docker image from the Bluemix Hub?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

In the [official docs](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/Containers/index.html) I did not find any mentioning of how to remove a Docker image from Bluemix.
Is it possible?
What is the "ice" command for that?

The `rmi` command does not work with `ice`:

```
ice: error: argument subparser_name: invalid choice: 'rmi' (choose from 'login', 'tlogin', 'ps', 'run', 'inspect', 'logs', 'start', 'stop', 'restart', 'pause', 'unpause', 'rm', 'images', 'search', 'info', 'ip', 'help')
```

Comment: There exists `docker rmi`. It seems like ice resembles docker a lot.Try  `ice rmi`

Comment: [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/7) might be related.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it is an "ice" specific issue.

Comment: Well, private IBM Containers registry is still a docker registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the new CLI at https://static-ice.ng.bluemix.net/icecli-2.0.zip

Once you download it install it with the following.

```
sudo pip install icecli-2.0.zip --upgrade
```

Please make sure you have at least Python 2.7.

This will upgrade the CLI and then you will have the `rmi` command.

```
usage: ice rmi [-h] [--registry REGISTRY] [--key PSSWD] IMAGE
ice rmi: error: too few arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the command `ice rm <container>` a try.

```
[08:40 AM] jsloyer@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro [Downloads]>ice rm
Target is container cloud. Invoking cloud service...
usage: ice rm [-h] CONTAINER
ice rm: error: too few arguments
```

More info at http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/Containers/index.html#container_cli__rm

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but this removes container, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to delete images on Bluemix using the IBM Containers Cloud Foundry plug-in ([documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_ov.html)).

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ cf ic login
docker@boot2docker:~$ cf ic rmi <image URL>
```